# mapkit direction and duration(time taken to reach destination)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, google-maps, mapkit

i am trying to create an iPhone app with will show routing on the map and also the time taken to reach the destination.

any direction or help on go about doing the above ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the default Mapkit. It will show the directions you must take and how long it will take to get there. Or you can just have the maps application open up to view the route in there. Just google how to add mapkit. There are tons of tutorials or google how to open up the maps app. Hope this helps.